How to terminate a child process in Rust?
There is a function name execute_command that implemented to handel infinitely commands like ping <ip> -t. so Im trying to terminate the child process in using .kill() if it lasts more than 20 seconds. but I can see it is still running in terminal. whats the problem? is there another way to do this?
use std::process::Command;
use tokio::time::{sleep, Duration, Instant};

async fn execute_command(command: &str) -> Result<String, std::io::Error> {

    let mut child = Command::new("powershell")
        .arg("-Command")
        .arg(command)
        .spawn()?;
    
    let start = Instant::now();
    loop {
        // Check if the process has completed
        match child.try_wait()? {
            Some(_) => {
                let output = child.wait_with_output()?;
                let response_text = String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout).to_string();
                return Ok(response_text)
            }
            None => {
                // Process hasn't completed yet, check if timeout has elapsed
                if start.elapsed() >= Duration::from_secs(20) {
                    child.kill()?;
                    return Ok("Failed to execute command: TimeOut".to_owned())
                } else {
                    // Wait a bit before trying again to avoid busy-waiting
                    sleep(Duration::from_millis(100)).await;
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}

i can see Reply from 192.168.31.7: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128 prints countnuously in terminal.

You're killing powershell, but your ping might or might not be killed, just drop the powershell -Command "wrapper".

hew can I do that?
I replaced child.kill()? to drop(child) but no change happened.
